# How can I concat a child array to a parent array in a multi level object and many ramifications?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

Given an object with an arbitrary depth of nested arrays how can I extract the distinct values of child arrays and transform them as a value.

For example:

```
const bigObj = {
    parent1: {
        subParent1: {
            user1: [1, 2, 3],
            user2: [3, 4, 5]
        },
        subParent2: {
            user3: [6, 7, 8],
            user4: [7, 8, 9]
        }
    },
    parent2: {
        subParent3: {
            user5: [a, b, c],
            user6: [d, e, f]
        },
        subParent4: {
            subSubParent1: {
                user7: [g, h, i],
                user8: [j, k, l]
            }
            user9: [m, n, o],
        }
    }
}
```

and I would like to transform it into something like this:

```
const bigObj = {
    parent1: {
        subParent1: {
            user1: [1, 2, 3],
            user2: [3, 4, 5],
            values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        },
        subParent2: {
            user3: [6, 7, 8],
            user4: [7, 8, 9],
            values: [6, 7, 8, 9]
        },
        values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    },
    parent2: {
        subParent3: {
            user5: [a, b, c],
            user6: [d, e, f],
            values: [a, b, c, d, e, f]
        },
        subParent4: {
            subSubParent1: {
                user7: [g, h, i],
                user8: [j, k, l],
                values: [g, h, i, j, k, l]
            }
            user9: [m, n, o],
            values: [g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
        },
        values: [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
    },
    values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o]
}
```

How can I achieve this with vanilla Javascript? I do not want to use libraries or frameworks, just plain JS. This is just an example, the object can have many levels and many arrays.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a recursive function that maps values to one level higher.

```js
const bigObj = {
  parent1: {
    subParent1: {
      user1: [1, 2, 3],
      user2: [3, 4, 5]
    },
    subParent2: {
      user3: [6, 7, 8],
      user4: [7, 8, 9]
    }
  },
  parent2: {
    subParent3: {
      user5: ["a", "b", "c"],
      user6: ["d", "e", "f"]
    },
    subParent4: {
      subSubParent1: {
        user7: ["g", "h", "i"],
        user8: ["j", "k", "l"]
      },
      user9: ["m", "n", "o"],
    },
  },
}

const mapValues = (obj) => {
  let ret = []
  for (key in obj) {
    // this is the recursion stopping condition: if the obj[key]
    // is an array, then recursion stops, the function doesn't
    // call itself
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
      // [...new Set(/*...*/)] is to ensure that only unique values
      // are in your values - according to your example
      ret = [...new Set([...ret, ...obj[key]])]
    } else {
      // here's the recursion: the function calls itself -
      // now with a different object as argument: obj[key]
      ret = [...new Set([...ret, ...mapValues(obj[key])])]
    }
  }
  obj["values"] = ret
  return ret
}

const fullList = mapValues(bigObj)

console.log("modified object:", bigObj)
```

Comment: use `Array.concat` method, `ret.concat(obj[key])` And `ret.concat(mapValues(obj[key]))`

Comment: @Nur no, I'd prefer not to - doesn't make any logical difference and I like the spread operator. Or is there any specific reason you're suggesting that?

Comment: no! its fine to use `...`, I just like method call

Comment: Thank you, is exactly what I wanted. I understand how you build the function, it is really helpful.

Comment: @dee_jay I'm glad that I could help :)

Comment: @Nur then OK - I admit, that there are setups that go better with `concat()`, but in this snippet I think this makes really no difference. But thx for the idea, anyways!

Comment: So much easier than my solution. Thanks I learned something!

Comment: @Kinglish if you haven't watched this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8lhxIOAfDss - 12 minutes and recursion becomes a breeze! :)

Comment: I did not saw that, This question already has answer 7m ago, not but when I about to post answer mine, And logic implementation exactly same!...

Answer (score 0):

This uses a recursive function and another helper to reduce re-using code. For demo purposes, I prepopulated the a,b,c variables

```js
let vars = "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q";
vars.split(",").forEach(l => {
  this[l] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
})


const bigObj = {
  parent1: {
    subParent1: {
      user1: [1, 2, 3],
      user2: [3, 4, 5]
    },
    subParent2: {
      user3: [6, 7, 8],
      user4: [7, 8, 9]
    }
  },
  parent2: {
    subParent3: {
      user5: [a, b, c],
      user6: [d, e, f]
    },
    subParent4: {
      subSubParent1: {
        user7: [g, h, i],
        user8: [j, k, l]
      },
      user9: [m, n, o],
    }
  }
}

const getValuesFrom = (tmpobj) => {
  let values = []
  Object.entries(tmpobj).forEach(obj => {
    if (Array.isArray(obj[1].values))
      values = values.concat(obj[1].values.filter(value => !values.includes(value)));
  })
  return values
}

const getObj = (obj) => {
  return Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, a, i) => {
    let b = {
      [a[0]]: a[1],
      values: []
    }
    if (!Array.isArray(a[1])) {
      Object.entries(a[1]).forEach(varr => {
        if (Array.isArray(varr[1])) {
          b.values = b.values.concat(varr[1].filter(value => !b.values.includes(value)));
        }
      })
    }
    acc.data.push(b)
    acc.values = acc.values.concat(b.values.filter(value => !acc.values.includes(value)));
    return acc
  }, {
    data: [],
    values: []
  })
}
let newobj = Object.entries(bigObj).map(parent => {
  let tmpobj = {
    [parent[0]]: getObj(parent[1])
  };
  tmpobj.values = getValuesFrom(tmpobj);
  return tmpobj;
}).map(obj => {
  obj.values = getValuesFrom(obj);
  return obj;
})

console.log('transformed: ', newobj)
```